# PiCamera Flask, start and stop preview

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I am creating a little web interface in Flask to control the Raspberry Pi camera using the PiCamera python module. I have a working index page which displays a stream from the camera. However, when I POST stop_preview() via an input button the app fails and I cannot work out what I am doing wrong. Here's some of my code so far.

This is part of my views.py

```
from flask import redirect, url_for, session, request, \
             render_template, Response
from simplepam import authenticate
from app.camera_pi import Camera
from app import app


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit']:
            Camera.StopPreview()
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("index.html", title="Home")


def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route. Put this in the src attribute of an img tag."""
    return Response(gen(Camera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

This is my index.html template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


 <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <img id="video_feed" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
        <form method="post">
          <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="StopPreview"></p>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is the camera_pi.py file (taken from Miguel Grinberg's github repo https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-video-streaming)

```
# The MIT License (MIT)
#
# Copyright (c) 2014 Miguel Grinberg
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.


import time
import io
import threading
import picamera
from app import camera_config


class Camera(object):
    thread = None  # background thread that reads frames from camera
    frame = None  # current frame is stored here by background thread
    last_access = 0  # time of last client access to the camera
    stop_camera = False

    def initialize(self):
        if Camera.thread is None:
            # start background frame thread
            Camera.thread = threading.Thread(target=self._thread)
            Camera.thread.start()

            # wait until frames start to be available
            while self.frame is None:
                time.sleep(0)

    def get_frame(self):
        Camera.last_access = time.time()
        self.initialize()
        return self.frame

    def StopPreview():
        Camera.stop_camera = True

    @classmethod
    def _thread(cls):
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
            # camera setup
            camera.resolution = camera_config.camera_resolution

            # let camera warm up
            camera.start_preview()
            time.sleep(2)

            stream = io.BytesIO()
            for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg',
                                                 use_video_port=True):
                # store frame
                stream.seek(0)
                cls.frame = stream.read()

                # reset stream for next frame
                stream.seek(0)
                stream.truncate()

                # if there hasn't been any clients asking for frames in
                # the last 10 seconds stop the thread
                if time.time() - cls.last_access > 10:
                    break
                elif Camera.stop_camera is True:
                    break
        cls.thread = None
```

I have added the "def StopPreview()" section and it is being called when I POST a submit button from the index page, but the app just crashes at this point.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: What does 'just crashes' mean?  Do you get a traceback? post it here

Comment: Yeah the traceback is: picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Camera component couldn't be enabled: Out of resources (other than memory)

Comment: Try another webcam-streaming in flask. It's implemented in alternative method. https://github.com/36rahu/webcam_streaming_flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `start_preview` and `stop_preview` methods of picamera just start and stop the preview, which is the overlay video that appears on the Pi's own display. These methods do not start or stop the camera itself.

To stop the camera, you have to get the background thread in method `_thread` to exit, in a similar way as it exits when 10 seconds of inactivity pass.

For example, you could add a `stop_camera` variable to the object, initialized with `False`. In your stop method you just flip the variable to `True` and return. Then in the background thread, you add a second condition based on the value of this variable in the conditional that checks for 10 seconds of inactivity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Miguel, thanks for your response. I have amended the camera_pi.py above to now include a stop_camera variable as you suggested but now I am getting a traceback error which states: ValueError: View function did not return a response. Also whilst this will stop the camera I am also hoping to be able to reload the preview without refreshing the whole page, would stopping and starting the camera be the best way to achieve this, or would I be able to just stop and start the preview somehow?

Comment: The `view function did not return a response` error is unrelated. All your Flask routes must return a response, even if it is an empty string. You are missing that in one of your routes, I guess the one you added to stop the camera. To restart the camera, just add another route that starts a new background thread.

Comment: Hi Miguel, I am still struggling to get my head around this. Please could you provide some code examples?

Comment: @RyanKowalewski I don't have anything readily available, what I have is what I wrote in my blog post and GitHub repository. Sorry.